# Как решить задание обоснованно кодом?

Tags: python

Исполнитель Редактор получает на вход строку цифр и преобразовывает её. Редактор может выполнять две команды, в обеих командах v и w обозначают цепочки символов.

```
1. заменить (v, w) 
2. нашлось (v)
```

Первая команда заменяет в строке первое слева вхождение цепочки v на цепочку w. Если цепочки v в строке нет, эта команда не изменяет строку. Вторая команда проверяет, встречается ли цепочка v в строке исполнителя Редактор.
Дана программа для исполнителя Редактор:

```
НАЧАЛО
ПОКА нашлось (900) или нашлось(8000) или нашлось(70)
  заменить(70, 8)
  заменить(900, 70)
  заменить(8000, 900)
КОНЕЦ ПОКА
КОНЕЦ
```

Известно, что на вход программы поступила строка из 71 символа. Определите минимальное четырехзначное число, которое может являться результатом работы исполнителя.
Я решил это задание вот таким кодом

```
for i in ['7', '8', '9']:
    s = '100' + i + '0' * 67
    while '900' in s or '8000' in s or '70' in s:
        s = s.replace('70', '8', 1)
        s = s.replace('900', '70', 1)
        s = s.replace('8000', '900', 1)
    print(s)
```

Можно ли решить это задание другим способом, типо метода перебора и тд

Comment: мне кажется, что эта задача вообще к программированию отношения не имеет. Так как исходная строка была 71 символ, то за вменяемое время 10^71 вы не переберёте. Всякие динамики может быть и могут помочь, но опять же, доказательство их корректности это уже математика. А если использовать математику, то можно и вообще код не писать.